# Laravel encrypter occassionally throws Payload is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, payload

I have a laravel site (v 5.7) in which I encrypt data, send to a processor, and receive it back. Every once in a while I will receive a payload is invalid. Stack trace below:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The payload is invalid. in D:\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:191
Stack trace:
#0 D:\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php(134): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->getJsonPayload(NULL)
#1 D:\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(382): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decrypt('eyJpdiI6ImVENCt...', false)
```

It appears that when it goes to run the decrypt the variable is set then when passing it along the framework it is suddenly a NULL value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well this is a shot in the dark.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm running into the same issue. I've not found any real guidance yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've been suffering the very same problem. You should use Xdebug to see if your situation is similar.

The stack trace was a little misleading, but it turned out that the CSRF token being created is having trouble at this line in `getJsonPayload`:

```
$payload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);
```

This is what actually returns `null` because when the generated token is base64_decoded, the result what looks to me like binary data as opposed to string data in JSON format.

Sadly, this is as far as I got...